# asp.net mvc route clashing with physical path in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I'm messing about with controller organisation and I've hit a problem.

If I have the following physical structure

```
/Home/HomeController.cs
/Home/Index.aspx
/Home/About.aspx
```

and I request the URI:

```
/Home/Index
```

I get a `403 Directory Listing Denied` :(

(im using a custom IControllerFactory and IViewEngine to look in this non-default path)

Why is this happening? (I know the 403 is because its hitting the `/Home` folder, but why is it hitting the folder?)

Why doesn't the UrlRoutingModule rewrite the route and let the controller pick up the request?

`Application_BeginRequest` fires, but then it seems to pass control back to IIS to try and serve from the filesystem.

Is it the UrlRoutingModule that defaults to a physical path if it exists before rewriting?

Is there a way to make this work?

N.B. Please don't suggest relocating my controllers etc. I know this is an obvious option, but that isn't the question ;)

Using IIS7 In Integrated Mode

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the routing abstraction will only route a request that has no equivalent file on disk.

You have no other option but to rename your folder structure.

-- Edit
No, actually you can disable that "feature" by setting the RouteExistingFiles property on RouteCollection.

Comment: then css files not loading

Answer (score 1):

The routing module does, indeed, have a preference for real files if they exist.  It seems that it must also not reroute after a failed accessibility check.

You do get the point that having separate controller/views reinforces the separation of concerns central to an MVC architecture, right?  I'd be concerned that keeping controllers/views in the same folder might confuse things for later developers.

Comment: hmm do you know where this "preference" code lives? i went on a reflector safari but a lion eated me :(

Comment: System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase)